# Reading a config file right when my Electron app starts

Tags: electron, vuejs3

I'm building a Electron app using Vue3.

I set up a simple home view, and all is working as expected. When the app starts, I'd like to load a config json and save the data to my Vuex store.

So far I come up with this:

First I have set up an ipcHandler to communicate with the main process:

```
import { app, ipcMain } from "electron";
import store from "@/store";

ipcMain.on("init-app", (settingsData) => {
    console.log("Init app", settingsData);
    store.commit('updateSettings', settingsData);
});
```

In my background.js file I send the "init-app" channel, when the window is created:

```
app.on('ready', async () => {
    createWindow().then((win) => {
        setupIpcHandlers();
        const settingsPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'settings.json');
        fs.readFile(settingsPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            const settingsData = err ? {} : JSON.parse(data);
            ipcMain.emit("init-app", settingsData);
        });

    });

})
```

And this is my updateSettings mutation in store/index.js:

```
mutations: {
    updateSettings(state, settings) {
        console.log("Updating settings", settings);
        state.appSettings = settings;
    }
},
```

When I start the app via yarn electron:serve, I can see in the console logs, in the terminal. The json file loads correctly, also the log in the mutation displays the correct data, but it is not stored in the state.

When I call the mutation later via user action, all is working fine.

Any ideas, how to fix it? Or maybe use a different approach?

Comment: You're trying to commit to a store before initialising the vue app. The store only works as expected after you install Vuex on a vue app. Why don't you import the data directly into the store (`import settingsData from './path/to/file'`)?

Comment: If you really wanted to commit to a store before the app uses it, you'd have to create an empty vue app, connect the store to it just so the store functions (a store can be used by multiple apps simultaneously). And then, after your real app mounted and connected to the store you could destroy the initial empty app, but that's an unnecessary complication, when you could import the data directly into the store, as I suggested above.

Comment: I can't import the file directly to the store, because it can change. The config file is read on the start, but can be rewritten later by changing settings in the app.

Comment: Which means the config file acts as a database/storage. You read it when you mount the app and place the data in store. From that point on, the store is the source of truth for your app. And you send messages to main to rewrite the file when the settings are changed, so next time you start the app and import the file contents, they're up to date. But that doesn't change the fact the easiest way to read the file contents is by importing it in the store.

Comment: And, before you ask, it can be done as you're trying to do it, but you're missing one piece of information: main needs to know when the vue app has mounted. At which point it can start committing. To make it work, you need to emit an event from the app on mounted, listen to it in main, so it can then read the file and then commit to the store. It's unnecessarily complicated (by comparison with importing the json into the store), but it would work.

Comment: The app is mounted before the window is created. I cant load the json that way, because when the app is mounted, the ipcHandlers are not initializes yet.

Comment: If im not mistaken, if I import it to the store as you suggest, when I build the app, the config is packaged into my app and cant be changed later

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was facing a timing issue where the Vue component is trying to communicate with the Electron main process before the window is fully created.

I restructured the logic a bit and here is a functioning updated code:

**ipcHandlers.js:**

```
import { app, ipcMain } from "electron";
const fs = require('fs');
const path = require('path');

const settingsPath = path.join(app.getPath('userData'), 'settings.json');


export const setupIpcHandlers = () => {

    ipcMain.on('get-settings', (event) => {
        fs.readFile(settingsPath, 'utf8', (err, data) => {
            event.reply('settings-loaded', err ? {} : JSON.parse(data));
        });
    });

    ipcMain.on('save-settings', (event, settingsData) => {
        fs.writeFile(settingsPath, JSON.stringify(settingsData), 'utf8', (err) => {
            // Handle error if necessary
        });
    });

}
```

inside **background.js:**

```
import { setupIpcHandlers } from './ipcHandlers.js';

app.on('ready', async () => {
    
    createWindow().then((win) => {
        setupIpcHandlers();
        win.webContents.send('window-ready');
    });

})
```

**store/index.js:**

```
import { createStore } from 'vuex'
const { ipcRenderer } = require('electron');

export default createStore({
    state: {
        appSettings: {},
    },
    getters: {
        getSettings(state) {
            return state.appSettings || {};
        }
    },
    mutations: {
        updateSettings(state, settings) {
            state.appSettings = settings;
        }
    },
    actions: {
        loadSettings({commit}) {
            if (ipcRenderer) {
                ipcRenderer.send('get-settings');
                ipcRenderer.on('settings-loaded', (event, settings) => {
                    commit('updateSettings', settings);
                });
            }
        },

        saveSettings({commit}, settings) {
            commit('updateSettings', settings);
            // I kept getting an object could not be cloned error when trying to send the settings object, so I created a copy of it.
            const settingsCopy = JSON.parse(JSON.stringify(settings));
            ipcRenderer.send('save-settings', settingsCopy);
        }

    },
    modules: {},

})
```

And finally the magic, that resolved the issue is in my **App.vue:** file, where I set up a window-ready listener which is fired from the background.js file when the window is fully created.

```
import { ipcRenderer } from "electron";

export default {
    components: {  },
    computed: { },
    mounted() {
        ipcRenderer.on('window-ready', () => {
            this.$store.dispatch('loadSettings');
        });
    }
}
```

With all that changed, my app loads the config file at creation and is able to save it later to the same file.

Hope it helps someone.